# Http 403.14 error(the web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am running my asp.net website through visual studio 2012. 
However when I click run I get this error in the browser: Http 403.14 error(the web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory) !

any suggestions to resolve this error?

Comment: Ok I'm struggling with this in VS2013 after following http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: @Robert The error itself means you have no default document (e.g. Index.aspx) and no default route (MVC/WebAPI) and are requesting the site's root without directory browsing enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure after years you probably have an answer already. But in case someone else is looking for an answer in the future.

For my problem, I didn't have to at anything to the web.config. I didn't think I would need to either as it was working previously.

Make sure no folder is named the same as your page, I had a folder called "blog" and a page named "blog.aspx", it was trying to load the folder, I noticed this in the link, changed the folder to blogContent, now it loads fine.

Answer (score 0):

Set default document for your home page or whatever your start page.

Following link will help you with that http://www.iis.net/learn/web-hosting/web-server-for-shared-hosting/default-documents

Comment: He's getting the 403.14 error when using VS2012 as the host.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to add an agular folder into my existing VS 2015 project, and make all url starting with angular re-written with angular/index by adding rewrite element in web.config. But I was getting the error with the url localhost:49667/angular/ although all other urls starting with angular worked, e.g. angular/xxxx.

I tried the common solutions suggested online, such as, enable document browsing, set default document, etc. None of these worked. Eventually, ErikE's answer here solve my problem:

[The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory. asp.net vs 2012 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731719/the-web-server-is-configured-to-not-list-the-contents-of-this-directory-asp-net)

It turns out I already have an angular folder in my app which contains all the angular code. As a result, I am no longer able to have access to the url localhost:49667/angular/ even though I create an angular controller. After I change the controller's name to something else, the error is gone.
Hopefully, this would help others out because few people mentions this answer online so far.