# The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory. asp.net vs 2012 error?

Tags: asp.net

Got following Error:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

this is how I linked css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/styles/StyleSheet.css" />
```

i am using master page for first time. i did added master page in iss server.
i enabled the directory setting in my iss 8.0

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/styles/StyleSheet.css" />

Comment: Add it to to the question itself, rather than as a comment...

Comment: i enabled the directory in my iss 8.0

Comment: I think the reason for this is because of not giving the correct physical path when adding the application. Be careful to give the correct path.

Comment: This is getting me in the right direction. Have a nice question badge. +1

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Have you tried setting the following within your web.config file :

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 15):

> The Web server is configured to not **list** the contents of this directory

The keyword in the error is **list**.

That sounds more like you do not have a `default document` set up. If you don't have one, nor don't request a specific document (e.g. `http://www.foobar.com/` or  `http://www.foobar.com/foo.html` respectively) IIS will not "know" what to "serve" to the browser nor will it, nor should you expect it to, **list** the contents of that directory (instead).

See: [Microsoft Support: Error 403.14](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942062)

Comment: This worked for me.  Thank you!  But for other new people, to make this adjustment go to your solution properties --> "Web" tab --> "Specific page" and browse to your default web page.  Try running it again.

Comment: yes my app is dotnet app and i dont know how to host my web api

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi please post a new question with details, and what you have tried so far, instead of commenting here.

Answer (score 6):

**A Short Story Of A Lost Controller, And A Happy Ending**

Let's say you have a controller called `Data`, in the project file `/Controllers/DataController.cs`. You can access it just fine via `http://yoursite.com/data`, which is handled by the `DataController.Index` action method.

Then, somehow, it breaks, and you start getting "The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory" when you visit this URL. Strangely, visiting `/data/index` still works! You try all the suggestions found online to make this work but can't seem to do it. What could it be?

Perhaps you ought to think about what the error means. It says that when you visit `/data`, it finds a directory there, but you aren't allowed to see the files in it. Setting aside the fact that your routing doesn't seem to work and it should, could there actually be a directory there?

Yes, there could! In your web project, you cleverly added folder `/Data`! This is a physical folder that takes precedence in the server's static routing rules (since you didn't rewrite those so physical files would be looked at *after* managed virtual paths).

The solution is thus to rename the folder, or rename the controller, one or the other. This will fix your problem quite speedily and you may then proceed on your merry way coding long into the night to the enveloping strains of techno Spanish mandolin trance music, with your trusty cat snoozing on your foot and the cold beverage of your choice beading up on the desk next to you!

Comment: I would upvote this answer twice if I could; once because it solved our issue, and once for the entertaining way in which is was written. Nice one!

Comment: @gerrod I'm very glad to have helped you! It took me at least 90 minutes to find and fix that one, sigh...

Answer (score 1):

The Ramesh Rajendran's answer must working, but you can use look at what is the modules your web application use and add in system.webServer tag on webconfig file to they use it. I had this error also in a test web application when I put it on Server IIS.

It's very strange not list the contents with the option enabled on IIS Web Server.

Answer (score 0):

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, then IIS don't understand what to serve as you don't have any Default aspx file in your site , i recommend you to add a aspx file by going to Add>NewItem>Webform>
Note: remember to check the box at bottom right , "select from master page"
after selecting , save all the pages and just open your default.aspx file and you will surely see the reflected design as you did in master page.

Master pages are not aspx file but serve as a template for other webpages , so you cant just open master page.

Answer (score -1):

Don't start the debugger while you are on the master page. EdSF pretty much summed up why. 
In addition, you also may need to set a default start page(right click, set as start page).

Answer (score -1):

You should define a default document value in web config and disable directory browsing.

```
<system.webServer>
<defaultDocument>
   <files>
      <add value="insertion.aspx" />
   </files>
</defaultDocument>
<directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
```